# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a simple database in which I have two tables, **Applications** and **Category**. Categories are dependent on Application, so I want to delete Category when Apps are deleted, For this purpose I used Foreign key in Category table. It works fine in local server, however when I upload it to online server, it show me error:
[image]

I tried a lot, but can't solve this issue. Can anyone suggest me please how to change my database. My database snippets are:

```
CREATE TABLE `app_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `app_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `app_category` (`app_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `app_category` FOREIGN KEY (`app_id`) REFERENCES `app_name` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: It is working fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check with table names because its working fine in my machine actually this error occurs when we have different data types

> ex: `id in app_name`,`app_id in app_category` need to have same data type with same count `int (11) not null`.